# GZipStream works when writing to FileStream, but not MemoryStream

Tags: c#, .net, gzipstream

If compress some json text, and write that it to a file using a `FileStream` I get the expected results. However, I do not want to write to disk. I simply want to memorystream of the compressed data.

Compression to `FileStream`:

```
string json = Resource1.json;

using (MemoryStream input = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
using (FileStream output = File.Create(@"C:\Users\roarker\Desktop\output.json.gz"))
{
    using (GZipStream compression = new GZipStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        input.CopyTo(compression);
    }
}
```

Above works. Below, the output memory stream is length 10 and results in an empty .gz file.

```
string json = Resource1.json;

using (MemoryStream input = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (GZipStream compression = new GZipStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        input.CopyTo(compression);

        byte[] bytes = output.ToArray();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Moving `output.ToArray()` outside the inner `using` clause seems to work. However, this closes the output stream for most usage. IE:

```
        using (MemoryStream input = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
        using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (GZipStream compression = new GZipStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                input.CopyTo(compression);
            }
            WriteToFile(output);
        }
```

where :

```
    public static void WriteToFile(Stream stream)
    {
        using (FileStream output = File.Create(@"C:\Users\roarker\Desktop\output.json.gz"))
        {
            stream.CopyTo(output);
        }
    }
```

This will fail on stream.CopyTo because the stream has been closed. I know I could make a new `Stream` from bytes of `output.ToArray()`, but why is this necessary? why does `ToArray()` work when the stream is closed?

**Final Edit:**

Just needed to use the contructor of the `GZipStream` with the `leaveOpen` parameter.

Comment: To be clear, `bytes.Length == 10` in the end.

Comment: Do you get the same behavior if you move `byte[] bytes = output.ToArray();` outside the inner `using` block?

Comment: Streams are like toilets.  You're not done with them until they're flushed.  Unless you're some kind of disgusting animal.  I mean, really.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34566559/is-it-possible-to-get-length-of-closed-memory-stream/34566825#34566825

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're calling `ToArray()` before you've closed the `GZipStream`... that means it hasn't had a chance to flush the final bits of its buffer. This is a common issue for compression an encryption streams, where closing the stream needs to write some final pieces of data. (Even calling `Flush()` explicitly won't help, for example.)

Just move the `ToArray` call:

```
using (MemoryStream input = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (GZipStream compression = new GZipStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        input.CopyTo(compression);
    }
    byte[] bytes = output.ToArray();
    // Use bytes
}
```

(Note that the stream will be disposed when you call `ToArray`, but that's okay.)

Comment: I'm confused because the output stream is considered closed after the inner using. I can use ToArray() and get all the bytes, but I cannot pass the `output` to other function to be treated like a memorystream. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Dave: Yes - basically you're using the extra functionality of `MemoryStream` (that it has the data in memory) but you can't use it as a regular stream. It's really, really handy to be able to do this - precisely in this sort of situation.

Comment: I edit'd the question, but I guess what you're saying is that if I want to access that data in memory, I need to copy those bytes into a new stream?

Comment: @Dave: No, I'm not saying that at all. You call `ToArray()`, and you get a byte array with the contents. Access that however you want to... there's no need to create a new stream with that data unless you want to. If you *need* it in the form of a stream, then yes, you'd create a new `MemoryStream` to wrap it. In some cases there are ways to make "wrapping" streams not close the underlying ones, but it's not universal.

Comment: Ahh, I can probably use the leaveOpen constructor arguement to do what I want.

Comment: I thought the whole point of working with Streams is so you don't have to create arrays (which chew up memory). Surely it's possible to pass in a stream and compress the contents to another stream. In my case I need a stream to pass to another method which "streams" the data to azure storage - ideally there would be no arrays in that process.

Comment: @tigerprawn: We can't really tell much about your context here. This answer is about arrays because the *question* is about arrays. Presumably in your context, you *don't* have arrays. If you're having difficulty with what you're trying to do, I suggest you ask a new question with a lot more detail.