# Why the length of zipped stream is always 10?

Tags: c#, gzipstream

I am testing some code. I am stuck with the following. What ever I write as `text`, the length of the zipped stream is always 10? What am I doing wrong?

```
var inStream = new MemoryStream();

var inWriter = new StreamWriter(inStream);

str text = "HelloWorldsasdfghj123455667880fgsjfhdfasdferrbvbyjun hbwecwcxqsz    edcrgvebrjnuj5juerqwetsrgfggshurhtnbvzkfjhguhgrgal;kjhao;rhl;zkfhg;aorihghg;oahrgarhguhh';aaeaeiaijeihjrhfidfhfidfidhh953453453";
inWriter.WriteLine(text);

inWriter.Flush();
inStream.Position = 0;

var outStream = new MemoryStream();
var compressStream = new GZipStream(outStream, CompressionMode.Compress);
inStream.CopyTo(compressStream);

compressStream.Flush();
outStream.Flush();
compressStream.Flush();

outStream.Position = 0;

Console.WriteLine(outStream.Position);
Console.WriteLine(outStream.Length);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34566559/is-it-possible-to-get-length-of-closed-memory-stream

Comment: @MethodMan At the moment I am not closing anything. It should not be that

Comment: But @MethodMan is right - until you Close it the compression stream doesn't know you've finished writing to it - so cannot complete its compression algorithm.

Comment: @PhillipH With using and leaveOpen, now it is working. I was about to post a self-answer. Instead you could post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until you Close it the compression stream doesn't know you've finished writing to it - so cannot complete its compression algorithm. Flushing flushes those parts it can flush, but until its been told you have completed adding new bytes it cannot flush its last package of compressed data.

Comment: As a note: If you want to use the resulting stream afterwards, you need to use it like this: GZipStream(outStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true)